# Convert current .vssettings to .vstheme for VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, themes, vssettings

I have downloaded the [Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) and a fonts/colors theme in the form of a `.vssettings` file (from [here](https://studiostyl.es/)). I want to be able to edit the file in the Color Themes window/tab/thing, but, to do that, I need to first convert the `.vssettings` file to a `.vstheme` or `.pkgdef` file. Is there any way to do this (without manually inputting the colors)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open **Tools > Customize Colors** and make a copy of the theme you want to work with, then edit it to get the theme editor open.([Visual hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKlMz.jpg))

Next, go to **Tools > Import and Export Settings** to install the `.vssettings` file you downloaded ([Details](http://studiostyl.es/home/faq)). Follow the prompts to optionally save your existing settings and apply the new ones.

Now, on the Theme editors toolbar there is a button with the letter A on it, press it. It will take all the settings that you just imported and put them in the theme you are editing.

Comment: Thanks, also works for VS2015 although the icons are different.